# What is the difference between val name: String? = null and val name: String?

Tags: android, kotlin, null

What is the difference between

```
val name: String? = null
```

and

```
val name: String?
```

I often use this in data classes but I'm not sure of the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is called default argument. When a class uses the constructor it can skip default arguments.

For example:

```
data class Dog(
   val breed: String? = null
)
```

It can be used like this:

```
val dog = Dog()
```

Which will make the `breed` null by default without need to explicitly pass the argument.

Otherwise:

```
data class Dog(
   val breed: String?
)
```

```
val dog = Dog() //does not compile because is missing the argument
val dog = Dog("something") //does work
val dog = Dog(null) //does work
```

The idea is that if you know a concept is going to be by default something you can make the instantiation easier. For example:

```
data class Flashlight(val light: Boolean = false)
```

A flashlight is not on by default so that works.

Comment: You can read about them here (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#default-arguments) - one of the benefits is if you call it using named arguments, you can just provide the arguments that you *do* want/need to specify, and everything else will use its default value. This means you can also use a single constructor / function for things instead of overloading it with multiple versions with different parameter combos!